# Why does Java not complain about the reserve word Float?

Tags: java, reserved-words

I entered this in Eclipse and expected it to be the wrong syntax but it is allowed.  Can someone please explain what is happening here? Should the `Float` and `Integer` keyword not be reserved?  What type of assignment is this?

```
Number Float = 99.455f;
Number Integer = 2;
```

Comment: Java always complains it's happens time to time. Don't worry!

Comment: This is not a Java code. Don't modify it. Nobody downvotes.

Comment: @RomanC: Yes, it is Java code. I've undone your tag removal.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If it is Java code how do I compile it?

Comment: @RomanC: With a Java compiler. I'm not being funny, there's nothing *technically* wrong with it, the `Float` and `Integer` there will just end up being variable names (as several of the answers point out). Try it yourself: Copy this to a file and run it through `javac`: http://pastie.org/5710476 (If that's your downvote on the question, you might reconsider.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a variable with the name `Float`.  That's all.  It's not a reserved word.  The compiler is not trying to interpret it as a class name due to the syntax of your statement.  It's not invalid, even if it is bad form.

Comment: I don't really accept the comment of bad form as I said in my question that I am only testing some syntax out in eclipse and didn't get what I expected, its not actual code that I am using. Thanks for the explanation though. :)

Comment: @user1987378: I don't think it was directed at you so much as just a general comment: It's possible, here's why, but it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

No, `Float` is not reserved word. `float` is reserved word. Here is [list of reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) in java

Answer (score 2):

because that isn't reserved, it is autoboxed.

Comment: *"because that isn't reserved..."* Right *"...it is autoboxed object..."* No, it's a class name. (Not my dv)

Answer (score 2):

Float(which is a wrapper class) isn't Java reserved keyword but float(which is a primitive) is.

Comment: I find it strange that in a post about how case matters, you used the wrong case for "Java" ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer haha, thanks, i was actually typing it from my mobile :P

Answer (score 2):

Java is case sensitive, `float` is reserved keyword but `Float` not.

Answer (score 2):

`Float` is not a reserved word. It is just a name of java.lang.Float class, and system library class names (even from `java.lang`) are not reserved. `float` is a reserved word. You can also have

```
int String = 1;
```

but I would not advise.

Answer (score 1):

How about these , these also compile. No deference from Float or Integer which are no reserved key words but Class names

```
            String String = "";
            Math Math = null;
            Object Object = null;
```